# Stock price Import issue for a newbie

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

a total newbie who started this week on python.  I have been reading Datacamp and some other online resources as well as Python without fear.

I wanted to test and see if I can import some data prices and copied code from the internet.  I cannot get it to work due to an error:  TypeError: string indices must be integers on line 10

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr #needed to read data from yahoo

#df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
#print (df.Close)

stock =('AAPL')
start_date = '2017-01-01'
end_date = '2017-12-10'

closes = [c['Close'] for c in pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start_date, 
end_date)]

for c in closes:
    print (c)
```

The line closes = [c.......] is giving me an error.

Any advice on how to fix this?  I am starting my journey and actually trying to import the close prices for past year for S&P500 and then save them to Excel.  If there is a snippet which does this already and I can learn from, please let me know.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please post the error message you're seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `get_data_yahoo` returns a single dataframe.

```
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start_date, end_date)
df.head()

                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
Date                                                                     
2017-01-03  115.800003  116.330002  114.760002  116.150002  114.311760   
2017-01-04  115.849998  116.510002  115.750000  116.019997  114.183815   
2017-01-05  115.919998  116.860001  115.809998  116.610001  114.764473   
2017-01-06  116.779999  118.160004  116.470001  117.910004  116.043915   
2017-01-09  117.949997  119.430000  117.940002  118.989998  117.106812   

              Volume  
Date                  
2017-01-03  28781900  
2017-01-04  21118100  
2017-01-05  22193600  
2017-01-06  31751900  
2017-01-09  33561900  

type(df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Meanwhile, you're trying to iterate over this returned dataframe. By default, a for loop will iterate over the columns. For example:

```
for c in df:
    print(c)

Open
High
Low
Close
Adj Close
Volume
```

When you replicate this code in a list comp, `c` is given each column name in turn, and `str[str]` is an invalid operation.

In summary, just doing `closes = df['Closes']` on the returned result is sufficient to obtain the `Closes` column.

Comment: Thanks!  So if I want to download the last 3 years of daily close prices for the S&P 500, I would need to run a loop and append to the DataFrame? Is there a call to Yahoo other than get_data_yahoo which would return the last x days of close prices for a list of 500 stocks?

Comment: @Confusedxx my knowledge of this API ends here... you might want to ask a new question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply looking to dump the dataframe to an Excel spreadsheet. This will get you there.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
df.head(2)

Out[12]:
                 Open       High    Low      Close  Adj Close     Volume
Date
2009-12-31  30.447144  30.478571  30.08  30.104286  26.986492   88102700
2010-01-04  30.490000  30.642857  30.34  30.572857  27.406532  123432400

df.to_excel('dump_aapl.xlsx')
```

If you just want the **Close** column:

```
df['Close'].to_excel('dump_aapl.xlsx')
```